# How to get Telegram audio (music) album cover using Telethon API client

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I want to get the URL or bytes of the Telegram audio documents (music) album cover using MTProto API and `Telethon` Python lib, but I could not find such a thing by checking audio message properties. There was a `thumbs` property for the message attached `media` property that was null.

***Note:*** When I download a media using `client.download_media` the cover is attached to the file, but I do not want to download it.

[image: Telegram audio/music album cover]
[image: Telegram audio/music album cover]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not through MTproto. each Telegram client gets it manually from a different provider, I'm going with [Android](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/5a31f93ec2022515e2ac044345563fecbb93cb75/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/messenger/MessageObject.java#L6746) implementation.

small is chat UI thumb, other is for player size.
This is only a test for the track in your screenshot.

Deal with commented parts yourself and pass a valid message object, and use aiohttp instead and make this async func.

```py
import requests

def get_cover(msg, limit=1, small=False):
    # if not (f := msg.file) and not all((f.title, f.performer)): return
    # performer, title = f.performer, f.title 

    performer, title = 'Sixthells', 'Mayhem'
    url = f"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term={performer} - {title}&entity=song&limit={limit}"
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A5297c Safari/602.1"}

    req = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
    if 200 >= req.status_code < 300:
        if (x := req.json())['resultCount']:
            small_url = x['results'][0]['artworkUrl100']
            file_url = small_url if small\
                       else small_url.replace('100x100', '600x600') 
                       # Telegram default. can increase 600x600. 
            return small_url, file_url

print(*get_cover(msg=None), sep='\n')
```

prints:
https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music125/v4/76/36/42/7636429b-fced-ce2f-162b-f4864a1eacee/artwork.jpg/100x100bb.jpg

https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music125/v4/76/36/42/7636429b-fced-ce2f-162b-f4864a1eacee/artwork.jpg/600x600bb.jpg